# Boto3 Get the Response status 200 only after Uploading the file to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a service A, that uploads the file `sample.txt` to S3 using boto3.
Service A should return HTTP response as 200 only after the file is uploaded (or next line in code needs to be executed only after file is successfully uploaded). How to check for the condition that the file is uploaded.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.upload_file(file_path, BUCKET_NAME, key)
```

I have tried above code, but the response object is `None`.
Any help appreciated. Thanks

Scenario is: There is another `Service B`, that calls `Service A` and downloads the file `sample.txt` from S3. Sometimes, the situation is that `Service B` unable to find the `sample.txt` in S3 (404- Not found) as `Service A` file upload didn't finish yet

Comment: An exception would be thrown if the upload failed. Otherwise you can assume that the file was successfully uploaded to S3.

Comment: @jarmod updated the question